# Auto resize and display image

Tags: angular, image

I am working on an angular app that asks the user to upload an image. I can make the image a thumbnail by doing this:

```
 .thumbnail {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}
.thumbnail img {
  height: 90%;

}

<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><img class="thumbnail" [src]= "element.vehImage"></td>
```

but what if I want to resize the image to 300x300 after that thumbnail is opened? Is that possible? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Looks like you need something like inline style: https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Comment: Do you want to resize the image on server and show it in your component or just change size of image in your component(just client)?

Comment: Just client, it can upload whatever size to server, but I want it displayed as 300x300